# How to find a window by his inner text?

Tags: find, window

I have Application X (not mine!) with Subform x1, x2, x3.

How can I find the subform by the inner text (e.g. a label in the subform)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer to [this question about Window Handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432566/questions-about-window-handles/2435424#2435424)